# Why I can't run a .java file in the command line?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run this in the command line: java InOut
There is a file InOut.java there, I can see it when I run the dir command.
But I always get "Could not find or load main class InOut". What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Eclipse by the way.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running it? You first need to compile the class using `javac`

Comment: When you are new to language, start with "hello world" example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Comment: Also "I'm using Eclipse" and "I'm trying to run this in the command line: `java InOut`" doesn't make sense. One of reasons we are using IDE like Eclipse is to avoid command line.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can run Java code, it must be compiled. Run the command `javac InOut.java` and then run `java InOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will automatically compile your saved Java files for you, so you don't actually need to do it on the command line. When running your programs in command line, you have to go to the bin folder, not the src folder. There, you should find InOut.class, and be able to run it.